# Katalon: No signature of method

Tags: groovy, cucumber, katalon-studio

I'm trying to call the test case in a groovy step definition. This test case calls a custom keyword.

The problem:

```
10-28-2019 04:12:05 PM Invita utente

Elapsed time: 1,962s

carrier.invita_utente.Invita_utente:70

Invita utente FAILED.
Reason:
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static com.kms.katalon.core.mobile.keyword.MobileBuiltInKeywords.callTestCase() is applicable for argument types: (null) values: [null]
Possible solutions: callTestCase(com.kms.katalon.core.testcase.TestCase, java.util.Map), callTestCase(com.kms.katalon.core.testcase.TestCase, java.util.Map, com.kms.katalon.core.model.FailureHandling)
```

custom k.

```
public class randomEmail {
    /**
     * Check if element present in timeout
     * @param to Katalon test object
     * @param timeout time to wait for element to show up
     * @return true if element present, otherwise false
     */
    @Keyword
    public String getEmail(String suffix,String prefix){
        int randomNo = (int)(Math.random() * 1000);
        return suffix + randomNo + "@" + prefix;
        }
}
```

script: step definition

```
@Then("Invita utente")
    def Invita_utente() {
        Mobile.setText(findTestObject('Carrier/28-invita utente/android.widget.EditText0 - Inserisci la ragione sociale dellazienda'),
                'pittigghiu', 0)
        Mobile.callTestCase(findTestObject('Test Cases/mobile random email'))
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/call-test-case.html#call-test-case-in-manual-view) you need to pass in the empty map as the argument list (provided you don't have any arguments). Also, you may set the failure handling and you need to use `findTestCase()` (not `findTestObject()`) when specifying the test case name.

Try the following line:

```
Mobile.callTestCase(findTestCase('Test Cases/mobile random email'), [:], FailureHandling.OPTIONAL)
```